# Why was Liore changed to a desert?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist, fma-brotherhood

I'm currently re-watching the original Fullmetal Alchemist and Brotherhood together, and one of the minor, yet obvious changes I noticed is that Liore is in the middle of a desert in the 2003 anime, but surrounded by forests and hills in Brotherhood.

[image: B]

[image]
I'm assuming it was not originally a desert in the manga (since Brotherhood is supposedly closer to the manga). **Is that true?** Was it even specified?
Either way, **why did they make this change for the TV series?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [The manga does not have Liore in a desert](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Reole)
2. Liore plays a much larger role in the first FMA than it does in the manga or *Brotherhood*

Liore was part of the country of [Ishval](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Ishval) in the first FMA. In both versions, Ishval is portrayed as a Middle-Eastern country in the desert that has a civil war that Amestris interferes with. The first FMA has the crux of that conflict happen in Leore (i.e. where Col Mustang earns his rank, but at a high cost). Leore also needs to be remote because,

> when Scar lures the Amestris army in, he turns the entire city into a transmutation circle, thus creating a Philosopher Stone.

Contrast this with *Brotherhood*, where

> Father makes the city into one of the points in the [Amestris transmutation circle](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Nationwide_Transmutation_Circle).

As such, the city more logically belonged in Amestris(analogous to Germany) to facilitate the *Brotherhood* storyline.

Comment: In *Brotherhood*, not only was Liore one of the points, Ishval was a *different point*.  Putting Liore in Ishval would obviously not make a whole lot of geographic sense, but it did need to be in the east for multiple reasons.  So you give it a different climate and biome to clearly distinguish it from Ishval.

Comment: Excellent I suspected as much: they needed it to facilitate later story changes. I'm still researching this myself to find more definitive sources. Thanks for adding the spoiler tags too.